# Выравнивание блока внутри блока

Tags: css3, html, css

Итак, заданы div.parent и div.child

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Вопрос касается всяческих положений блока div.child внутри div.parent
Как реализовать некоторые вещи я знаю, некоторые -- нет. Прошу проверить/поправить ошибки и подсказать, то что я не знаю.

В моей терминологии положение задается двумя параметрами: горизонтальное выравнивание и вертикальное выравнивание. Наример: **лево-верх** обозначает положение блока div.child в левом верхнем углу блока div.parent.

- **лево-верх**

  .child { margin-right: auto; }
- **центр-верх**

  .child { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
- **право-верх**

  .child { margin-left: auto; }
- **лево-центр** (*не знаю*)
- **право-центр** (*не знаю*)
- **центр-центр** (*не знаю*)
- **лево-низ**

  .parent { position: relative; }
  .child { position: absolute; left:0; bottom:0 }
- **центр-низ**(*не знаю*)
- **право-низ**

  .parent { position: relative; }
  .child { position: absolute; right:0; bottom:0 }

И ещё, расскажите, что изменится и не изменится:

1. Если ширина и высота parent известна
2. Если ширина и высота и parent и
       child известны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.parent{
position:relative
}

.child{
position:relative; //или absolute, fixed

top:10px; //отступ сверху

left:15px; //отступ слева

}
```